# regex match after given string

Tags: regex

```
{{"name":"alpha",
 "age":"23",
 "sex":male",
 "location":"U.S"
 }
 {"name":"beta",
 "age":"23",
 "sex":male",
 "location":"Cambodia"
}}
```

If I give a name, my regex should return the location for that name.
Suppose the name is given as a variable, then I try,

```
"name":"alpha"[\d\D]*"location":"(.+?)"
```

I always get the last location with this expression. How can I get the location based on the name? Any help?

Comment: Don't use regex to extract data from JSON.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What do lazy and greedy mean in the context of regular expressions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions)

Comment: @trincot What if you only have regexes available? Okay, you can write a full JSON parser but that's a bit overkill for extracting a string from some JSON data.

Comment: @user2626431, can you please specify the programming environment you are using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You always get the last one because `[\d\D]*` is matching everything in between and Regexes try to always match as much as possible. If your Regex engine knows about *non-greedy* matches (and it looks like it does because you use a non-greedy match at the location yourself: `+?`), you should be able to use this:

```
"name":"alpha"[\d\D]*?"location":"(.+?)"
```